# React Django Rest Framework send nested data

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

How can I send multipart/form data from React to DRF with axios correctly?

I have nested serializer in Djnago Rest Framework:

```
class ImageTaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = ImageTask
    fields = ('image', )


class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ImageTaskSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ('images', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        lesson = self.context.get('view').kwargs.get('pk')
        task = Task.objects.create(user=user, lesson_id=lesson, text=validated_data['text'])
        if 'images' in validated_data:
            for image_data in validated_data['images']:
                ImageTask.objects.create(task=task, **image_data)
        return task
```

I guess, my data mast be like this:

```
{
    text: e.target.text.value,
    images: [
       { image: @PICTURE_FILE_HERE },
       { image: @PICTURE_FILE_HERE },
       { image: @PICTURE_FILE_HERE }
    ]
}
```

I have const [taskImages, setTaskImages] = useState([]) with data for example:

```
[
    {
        "path": "15.jpg"
    },
    {
        "path": "16.jpg"
    }
]
```

I`m trying like this:

```
const params = new FormData();
params.append('text', e.target.text.value)
taskImages.forEach( img => {
    params.append('images', [{'image': img}]);
})

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL,
        params,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}
    });
```

But in the DFR I've got request.data:

```
<QueryDict: {'text': ['Its my test task'], 'images': ['[object Object]', '[object Object]', '[object Object]']}>
```

And I need something like this:

```
<QueryDict: {'text': ['Its my test task'], 'images': [{'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 1.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}, {'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 2.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}, {'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 3.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}]}>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show me the view also?

Comment: Try debug the API on Postman or any other API Client. It seems there is no issue on backend.

Comment: I changed my answer. It was the solution in the frontend. Please check.

Comment: Yes its not the backend essue, the question about how send data correctly from the fronend side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've got the right result:

```
taskImages.forEach((img, index) => {
                params.append(`images[${index}]image`, img);
            })
```

Hope, it's helpfull for another developers

Answer (score 1):

I think You don't need to create the additional array in the frontend.

```
taskImages.forEach( img => {
    params.append('images', img);
})
```

Comment: It's not working. In this case I've got the <QueryDict: {'text': ['Its my test task'], 'images': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 1.jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: 2.jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: 3.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}> But I need the list with keys like this: {image: File} I don't now how to get it. I'm trying like `params.append('images', {'image': img});` But get:
`<QueryDict: {'text': ['Its my test task'], 'images': ['[object Object],[object Object]']}>` Its not correct